# How to select HTML element by id/class inside foreignobject inside SVG using raw JS

Tags: svg

The SVG is hardcoded inside the HTML of the HTML page. The HTML inside the foreignobject is working and responding to direct editing inside the code editor, but I cant select/manipulate the style of the elements using raw JS.

```
<body>
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svgId" version="1.1">
        <foreignObject requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="50" height="50">
            <div id="toModify" style="left:10px;"></div>
        </foreignObject>
    </svg>
</div>
```

document.?????('toModify').style.left = 20 + 'px';

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var thing = document.getElementById("toModify")

console.log(thing)

thing.style.left = 20 + 'px'

console.log(thing)
```

```html
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svgId" version="1.1">
        <foreignObject requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="50" height="50">
            <div id="toModify" style="left:10px;"></div>
        </foreignObject>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I think this is what you want?